# Django 3 InvalidTemplateEngineError

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to load the detail page html template but appears to throw a error. Which I am trying to debug still new to django but most of the time can sort of figure it out. But at a total loss on this.

Something to do with template engine either in setting.py or the template view or url. I think its something in the settings for the template.

I did some searches with no luck. There no errors in debug console in virtual studio. Just when i go the the url from the html templates. Any feed back or tips on how to read the error better would be appreciated.

```
"Set a unique NAME for each engine in settings.TEMPLATES."

             .format(", ".join(duplicates)))

     return templates

 def __getitem__(self, alias):

     try:

         return self._engines[alias]

…

     except KeyError:

         try:

             params = self.templates[alias]

         except KeyError:

             raise InvalidTemplateEngineError(

                 "Could not find config for '{}'
```

[image: picture of error]

I assume I am supposed to configure the basic_app/school_detail.html in the template section of the settings.py. This is where I am stuck.

raise InvalidTemplateEngineError(
django.template.utils.InvalidTemplateEngineError: Could not find config for 'basic_app/school_detail.html' in settings.TEMPLATES

This is the error that gets raised.

InvalidTemplateEngineError at /basic_app/1/

Could not find config for 'basic_app/school_detail.html' in settings.TEMPLATES

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/1/
Django Version:     3.0.4
Exception Type:     InvalidTemplateEngineError
Exception Value:

Could not find config for 'basic_app/school_detail.html' in settings.TEMPLATES

Exception Location:     C:\Users\taylo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py in **getitem**, line 71
Python Executable:  C:\Users\taylo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.2
Python Path:

['C:\Users\taylo\django\Advanced_Django_CBV\advcbv',
 'C:\Python\Python37\Lib',
 'C:\Python\Python37\DLLs',
 'C:\Python\Python37\Lib\lib-tk',
 'C:\Python\Python37\Scripts',
 'C:\Python\Python37\tcl',
 'C:\Python\Python37\Tools',
 'C:\Users\taylo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python38.zip',
 'C:\Users\taylo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\taylo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib',
 'C:\Users\taylo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32',
 'C:\Users\taylo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages',
 'C:\Users\taylo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 4 May 2020 16:24:46 +0000

===================================================================

settings.py

================================================================

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,

        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

===================================================================

School_detail.html

================================================================

```
{% extends "basic_app/basic_app_base.html" %}

{% block body_block %}

<div class="jumbotron">


<h1>Welcome to the School Detail Page </h1>
    <h2></h2>
    <p><b>Name: </b>{{school_detail.name}}</p>
    <p><b>Principal: </b> {{school_detail.principal}}</p>
    <p><b>Location: </b>{{school_detail.location}}</p>
    <h3><b>Students: </b></h3>

{% for student in school_detail.students.all %}
 <p>{{student.name}} who's student id is {{student.info}}</p>
{% endfor %}

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

[image]

===================================================================

## basic_app.html

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    Principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    School = models.ForeignKey(School,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='students')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**image of directory**

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from basic_app import views

app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name='list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name='detail')

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from . import models


class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

class SchoolListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'schools'
    model = models.School
    # returns school_list

class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'school_detail'
    model = models.School
    template_engine = 'basic_app/school_detail.html'
```

i tried to change settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
```

I also changed this but also didn't work

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
```

Comment: did you get it fixed? How you fixed it?

Comment: turned out to be i was not in my virtual environment. it was not a issue with Django itself but with my environment. I activated it and it was fixed.